# Html template for outlook app email not rendering as expected

Tags: c#, html, email, outlook, html-email

I am sending html template to mail with C#. The email I sent has the following issues:

- Html tags and css works fine in browser and mobile outlook, But it
  coming in plain text in the Outlook desktop app. (I have inline css and tables)
- And images do not appear at all. blockedimgsrc includes urls in
  google chrome outlook. In gmail, the src of the image tag does not
  come at all.

How can i fix these? can someone help?

Comment: You should add your code :)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. Make sure the mail is not in junk, move it to inbox. :)